# Placing two Divs side by side in a sidebar

Tags: css, wordpress, html

I have div'd up the Occasion and Project Type sections in my right side bar. I want them to stand side-by-side. Previously, I tried using tables to acheive this but was recommended against such practice. Is it possible to attain this? If anyone could help guide me through this, I'd really appreciate it. I had this made for me and need to edit the code to meet my new needs.

http://www.merrimentdesign.com is the website

I want it to look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, your site looks better in its current state. The right sidebar is pretty narrow, so stacking the "Occasion" and "Project Type" lists side-by-side will force line-breaks within the text-links, ie text-links that are too wide for the column will extend to the line below. The alternative would be to reduce the text-size, but doing so will make it harder to read.

Comment: I did think about leaving it, but I mainly want people to be able to see more content in the right bar upon first accessing the site.